# Accessing variables from imported component react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Lets say I have my main component, where if the type of {data} is "textSingles" I render the TextSingle component:

```
const Information = (props) => {

const data = props.data
return (
<View>
<Text>Information</Text>
{data.type == "textsingle" &
<TextSingle data={data}/>
}
</View>
 )}
```

Here is my TextSingle component":

```
const TextSingle = (props) => {

    const [item, setItem] = useState(props.data)
    
    const [text, setText] = useState('')

return (
    <View style={[styles.card, styles.shadowProp]}>

            {/* card label */}
            <View style={styles.cardHeaderTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.cardHeaderText}>{item.label}</Text>
            </View>
    
            {/* input container */}
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput 
              style={styles.textInput}
              placeholder='Enter Text'
              onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              placeholderTextColor='#949494'
              ></TextInput>
            </View>
           
          </View>

)
}
```

Within my Information component I am rendering TextSingle. With in TexSingle I have a text input, and that value sets the "text" var.

In this case I want to send the answer to firebase.

How do I get the value of that text input in Information component?

Answer (score 0):

use can use hook names `useimperativehandle` for use child functions in parent class. if you don't want to and you can pass function from parent here's it

in your `information component`

```
const Information = (props) => {
 const data = props.data
 const [text, setText] = useState('')
return (
<View>
  <Text>Information</Text>
   {data.type == "textsingle" &
  <TextSingle data={data} onChangeText={text => setText(text)}/>
   }
</View>
)}
```

and in your `textsingle`

```
const TextSingle = (props) => {

    const [item, setItem] = useState(props.data)

    

return (
    <View style={[styles.card, styles.shadowProp]}>

            {/* card label */}
            <View style={styles.cardHeaderTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.cardHeaderText}>{item.label}</Text>
            </View>

            {/* input container */}
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput 
              style={styles.textInput}
              placeholder='Enter Text'
              onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              placeholderTextColor='#949494'
              ></TextInput>
            </View>
           
          </View>

)
}
```